# Editing my /etc/host.deny

Tags: security, unix, firewall, hosts

I'm being trolled by China, and don't know why I can't block their request to my server.

**//host.deny**

```
ALL: item.taobao.com
ALL: 117.25.128.*
```

But when I watch the error log on my webserver `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` the requests are still being allowed through.

**Question:** Why isn't my host.deny config working?

Comment: *I'm being trolled by China...* - LOL!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KeithThompson didn't even know about that community

Comment: Maybe try `iptables`? (I'm from China, never mind)

Comment: @KevinGuan yea I tried iptables `iptables -A INPUT -s 117.25.128.13 -j DROP` but still coming through. (Do you know what oxygen :D )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosts deny will not block every socket connection, only on apps that rely on hosts.deny which is ssh, inetd, and a few others. To block all connections you need to use `iptables`.

It varies from distro to distro but the command line is something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 117.25.128.0/24 -j DROP
```

You'll need to use [**CIDR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation (ie, `a.b.c.d/x`) to do ranges. To wildcard the last digit change (class C network) it to a zero and use `/24`. For the last two IPs change them to zero and use `/16`.

Comment: ahh that might be the trick I've been using the `*` wild card selector

Comment: @KevinGuan so I figured I need to use -I instead -A to input it at the beginning of the file instead of the bottom (-A), apparently precedence is the first matching rule, thank you for your help.

Comment: @JordanDavis: Ah, yeah. No problem :P